# I try to get the url of the image I uploaded to storage, the codes I find are very old

Tags: swift, image, firebase, url, firebase-storage

I try to get the url of the image I uploaded to storage (https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mismascotasgb-oficial.appspot.com/o/petImage%2Fq5ABEFEWZNX7PqTJZ9Nm.jpg?alt=media&token=12b8c0b7-d65a -441c-a2d8-cfb55cf8498d).

I have searched the internet a lot but I only find old publications the most recent one I found shows me this code, but when I execute it it does not enter, the internal part of the code is skipped.

```
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let newDocument = db.collection("pets").document()
        pid = newDocument.documentID

        pid = newDocument.documentID
        let pidJPG = pid + ".jpg"

        let storageRef = RefStorage.petImages.reference().child(pidJPG)

        if let uploadData = self.imagePet?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2){

            storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error: \(String(describing: error))")
                    return
                }
            }

            urlImagePet = storageRef.description
            storageRef.downloadURL(completion: {(url, error) in
                if error != nil {
                 print(error!.localizedDescription)
                   return
                }
                self.image = url!.absoluteString
            })
        }
        db.collection("pets").document(pid).setData(toDictionary()) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("\n--------------------------------------")
                print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                print("--------------------------------------\n")
            } else {
                print("\n--------------------------------------")
                print("Document successfully written!")
                print("--------------------------------------\n")
            }
        }
    }



func toDictionary() -> [String : Any]{
        return[
            "pid" : pid,
            "urlImagePet" : urlImagePet,
            "image" : image
        ]

    }
```

Comment: urlImagePet = storageRef.description save (gs://....), but I need (https://...), I just try different options and I need both urlImagePet I need (gs://) and image I need (https://)

Comment: If **inside** the `storageRef.downloadURL(completion:` completion handler you print `url!.absoluteString`, do yuo get the URL?

Comment: No, I cannot print it inside, @FrankvanPuffelen and, Can you tell me the difference between both urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calls to `putData`, `downloadURL` and `setData` are all asynchronous. This means that the result from those calls is only available inside their completion handlers. To correctly use these results, you need to nest the calls, just like you already do for the error handling.

So something like:

```
if let uploadData = self.imagePet?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2) {

    storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        // once you get here, the data is uploaded to Cloud Storage, and 
        // you can get the download URL

        storageRef.downloadURL(completion: {(url, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            // once you get here, you have the download URL, so you can
            // write it to the database

            let data = [
                "pid" : newDocument.documentID,
                "urlImagePet" : storageRef.description,
                "image" : url!.absoluteString
            ]

            newDocument.setData(data) { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("Document successfully written!")
                }
            }

        })

    }


}
```

Comment: thanks. You were right, that worked perfectly for me.